# Camel beanio mapping file outside the war

Tags: apache-camel, bean-io

I'm using camel beanio component to marshal and unmarshal the data inside the file.

```
<beanio id="myBeanio" mapping="classpath:beanio-mapping-file-config.xml"
            streamName="myStreamName" />
```

It is working fine in tomcat but not working in jboss.
So I need to keep the beanio mapping xml outside the war file.
By mentioning actual path of mapping xml file for mapping attribute, it is working fine.
But I need to get the beanio mapping xml path from environment variable or from properties file.
So with below changes,

```
<beanio id="myBeanio" mapping="file:${env:env_var_name}/beanio-mapping-file-config.xml"
            streamName="myStreamName" />
```

or

```
<beanio id="myBeanio" mapping="file:{{prop_name}}/beanio-mapping-file-config.xml"
            streamName="myStreamName" />
```

I'm getting org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.FileNotFoundException

The environment variable/property is not getting replaced with the actual value.
Camel version used is 2.12.1

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What XML configuration it is? blueprint, spring, other?

Answer (score 1):

This i not possible today. You cannot refer to ENV in the mapping field in beanio.

That would require an ENH which I have logged:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9540